# Upload subdirectory transferutility S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transferutility

I want to upload all the files/folder inside a directory to a S3 bucket. I want to upload including the all the files in all the sub directories. I thought of using TransferUtility to do this. Though the link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadDirDotNet.html) says that ***'By default, Amazon S3 only uploads the files at the root of the specified directory. You can, however, specify to recursively upload files in all the subdirectories.'*** but I couldnt find a way to do this. I coundnt find any property where I can mention to include all the sub directories. I tried using `SearchOption = System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` and `SearchPattern = "*"` to achieve this, but still it uploaded only the files in the top most directory. Please help me in this. Thanks.

I'm using the below code,

```
TransferUtility directoryTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);

                TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest uRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest()
                {
                    Directory = dirPath,
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    SearchOption = System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories,
                    SearchPattern = "*"
                };

                directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(dirPath, bucketName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me: I set the options on the `UploadDirectory` method and used `"*.*"` as the search pattern.

```
    directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(dirPath, 
                                             bucketName,
                                             "*.*",
                                             SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```